# Reading an nth line of a textfile in python determined from a list

Tags: python

I have a function `gen_rand_index` that generates a random group of numbers in list format, such as `[3,1]` or `[3,2,1]`

I also have a textfile that that reads something like this:

> red $1
>
> green $5
>
> blue $6

How do I write a function so that once python generates this list of numbers, it automatically reads that # line in the text file? So if it generated [2,1], instead of printing [2,1] I would get "green $5, red $1" aka the second line in the text file and the first line in the text file?

I know that you can do print(line[2]) and commands like that, but this won't work in my case because each time I am getting a different random number of a line that I want to read, it is not a set line I want to read each time.

```
row = str(result[gen_rand_index]) #result[gen_rand_index] gives me the random list of numbers
file = open("Foodinventory.txt", 'r')
for line in file:
    print(line[row])
file.close()
```

I have this so far, but I am getting this

> error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[4, 1]'

I also have gotten

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

butI have tried replacing str with int and many things like that but I'm thinking the way I'm just approaching this is wrong. Can anyone help me? (I have only been coding for a couple days now so I apologize in advance if this question is really basic)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Lil Tix. Did you mean to write `[gen_rand_index()]` instead of `[gen_rand_index]` ? Also, it is a bit unclear what the function actually does, does it return a  list of nums? or a single random num?

Comment: @Srini thank you very much! I should clarifiy....  gen_rand_index is just the name i assigned                                                                            gen_rand_index = random.randrange(len(result))
        row = str(result[gen_rand_index])

Comment: @srini, so the program asks the user for how many numbers they want, and the sum they want the numbers to equal to. So if they wanted 2 random numbers that equal to 5, the program would output [4,1] or [3,2], etc. This entire process was named to be [gen_rand_index]. These numbers would also correspond to a certain line number in the textfile and this is what I'm struggling with. It ends up printing the entire textfile rather than printing the line i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let us first get some stuff out of the way

Whenever you access something from a list the thing you put inside the box brackets `[]` should be an integer, eg: `[5]`. This tells Python that you want the 5th element. It cannot `["5"]` because `5` in this case would be treated as a string

Therefore the line `row = str(result[gen_rand_index])` should actually just be `row = ...` without the call to `str`. This is why you got the TypeError about list indices

Secondly, as per your description `gen_rand_index` would return a list of numbers.

So going by that, why don;t you try this

```
indices_to_pull = gen_rand_index()
file_handle = open("Foodinventory.txt", 'r')
file_contents = file_handle.readlines() # If the file is small and simle this would work fine
answer = []

for index in indices_to_pull:
    answer.append(file_contents[index-1])
```

#### Explanation

1. We get the indices of the file lines from `gen_rand_index`
2. we read the entire file into memory using `readlines()`
3. Then we get the lines we want, *Rememebr to subtract 1 as the list is indexed from 0*

Comment: Wow this worked absolutely beautifully! Thank you so much for your help and explanations!!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you're trying to index a string variable (`line`) with a string index (`row`). Presumably `row` will contain something like `'[2,3,1]'`.

However, even if `row` was a numerical index, you're not indexing what you think you're indexing. The variable `line` is a string, and it contains (on any given iteration) one line of the file. Indexing this variable will give you a single character. For example, if `line` contains `green $5`, then `line[2]` will yield `'e'`.

It looks like your intent is to index into a list of strings, which represent all the lines of the file.

If your file is not overly large, you can read the entire file into a list of lines, and then just index that array:

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

print(lines[2]).
```

In this case, `lines[2]` will yield the string `'blue $6\n'`.

To discard the trailing newline, use `lines[2].strip()` instead.

Comment: fp.readlines() is a bad idiom because it attempts to read everything into memory.

Comment: @JeromeBaek In this case, reading everything into memory is kind of the point. Which is why I added the disclaimer "If your file is not overly large".

Comment: @JeromeBaek Moreover, your own answer also attempts to read everything into memory. You just do it with a loop instead of using `readlines()`. The resulting list your method creates is no smaller than the one `readlines()` returns.

Comment: Correct. The better solution here is `arr = list(f) `

Comment: @JeromeBaek That saves you the trouble of typing a loop, but it still reads the entire file into memory. Which isn't a bad thing in this case, again assuming the file isn't prohibitively large.

Comment: `list(f)` does not read the entire file into memory. In the `with open(...) as f` case `f` is a generator. A `list(f)` is an under-the-hood generator with some syntactic sugar such as element indexing.

Comment: @JeromeBaek Yes, `list(f)` *does* read the entire file into memory. It *uses* `f` as a generator, but the list it returns is not itself a generator or an iterator. It's a list. Just like with any other usage of `list(<some iterable>)`. Nowhere does any of the python documentation say that `list(f)` returns a generator. In fact, I tested both `list(f)` and `f.readlines()` with a very large (~140MB) text file, while using `top` to monitor memory before and after the file read. The results were pretty much identical. Memory usage spiked by 237.5MB with `list(f)` and 238.4MB with `f.readlines()`

Comment: @JeromeBaek That ~1MB difference (on a ~140MB file) is most likely due to some implementation details (probably leftover buffers used internally by the `readlines` implementation), but either way, it's obvious that `list(f)` doesn't return a generator object, but rather, it does indeed read the entire contents of the file into memory.

Comment: @JeromeBaek BTW, the above tests were with Python 2.7.12. I re-ran the tests with Python 3.5.2, and this time the memory increase was identical between the two methods, which probably means that they got rid of the one-off implementation of `readlines` and turned it into an alias for `list(f)`. But again, both methods produce an identical increase in memory usage.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for enlightening me. If len(row) << len(list(f)), and len(list(f)) is prohibitively large, there is still a O(len(list(f))) solution where you read into memory all lines that exist in row and then print them out in order.

Comment: @JeromeBaek I don't have any issues with *not* reading entire files into memory. *Most* of the time, you don't want to read an entire file into memory. But in OP's case, where he requires non-sequential access to the file, and it seems as though the file is probably reasonably small, I don't see a need to go out of the way to avoid reading in the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go line by line and raise some issues.

```
row = str(result[gen_rand_index]) #result[gen_rand_index] gives me the random list of numbers
```

Are you sure it is `gen_rand_index` and not `gen_rand_index()`? If `gen_rand_index` is a function, you should call the function. In the code you have, you are not calling the function, instead you are using the function directly as an index.

```
file = open("Foodinventory.txt", 'r')
for line in file:
    print(line[row])
file.close()
```

The correct python idiom for opening a file and reading line by line is

```
with open("Foodinventory.txt.", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

This way you do not have to close the file; the `with` clause does this for you automatically.

Now, what you want to do is to print the lines of the file that correspond to the elements in your variable `row`. So what you need is an `if` statement that checks if the line number you just read from the file corresponds to the line number in your array `row`.

```
with open("Foodinventory.txt", "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == row[i]:
            print(line)
```

But this is wrong: it would work only if your list's elements are ordered. That is not the case in your question. So let's think a little bit. You *could* iterate over your file multiple times, and each time you iterate over it, print out one line. But this will be inefficient: it will take time O(nm) where n==len(row) and m == number of lines in your file.

A better solution is to read all the lines of the file and save them to an array, then print the corresponding indices from this array:

```
arr = []
with open("Foodinventory.txt", "r") as f:
    arr = list(f) 
for i in row:
    print(arr[i - 1]) # arrays are zero-indiced
```